# Difference between <catalog_category_default> and <catalog_category_view>

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, theme

in **vendor.xml** file
Difference between

```
<catalog_category_default >       
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="vendor/vendor" name="vendor" template="vendor/vendor.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
```

and

```
<catalog_category_view>       
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="vendor/vendor" name="vendor" template="vendor/vendor.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
```

both are showing my vendor form on all category page but what they have diff..

1. I want to show a vendor block on particular category. how i show.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`catalog_category_view` is loaded for all the category pages.
It's the default layout handler for the category page. The category page maps to the `catalog` module, `category` controller, `view` action.

`catalog_category_default` is loaded only for categories that are not marked as anchors.
There is also a layout handle called `catalog_category_layered` that is loaded for categories marked as anchor.

If you want to show a particular block for one single category, you can either make it as a static block and use the category display settings. Set the display mode as `Static block and products` and select the appropriate static block.
Or you can use the layout handle `<CATEGORY_{ID_HERE}>`. replace `{ID_HERE}` with the category id.
Also you can try to use the custom xml layout field in the category display settings in the backend.

**[EDIT]**
To use the category handle do this:
Let's say that you want to add a block for category with id 10.
Add this in the layout

```
<CATEGORY_10>
    <reference name="content"> 
        <block type="vendor/vendor" name="vendor" template="vendor/vendor.phtml" />     
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_10>
```

Comment: Again I failed to answer first. Kudos to @Marius. I learned this point from you of course. You are a great teacher :)

Comment: How i add <CATEGORY_{ID_HERE}> in my xml file my code is :<catalog_category_view>       
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="vendor/vendor" name="vendor" template="vendor/vendor.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>

Comment: @PankajR. See my update

Answer (score 1):

`catalog_category_view` page handler contains layout that will render when a category page view is requested. However layout placed in `catalog_category_default` handler will not be rendered for every category page. It render only if that category is not a layered category. For layered category, instead of `catalog_category_default`,`catalog_category_layered` will be used.

A category become default or layered depend upon the setting that we made through admin. If we need layered navigation in a category, we need to set `isAnchor` option to `yes` for that category through admin. For that case the layout handler used will be `catalog_category_layered`. If the option set to `No`, then the handler used by Magento will be `catalog_category_default`.

But for both cases, `catalog_category_view` will use. For every category view request, this handler will process

Answer (score 0):

In a simple  word, Magento is `calling  catalog_category_view as   default category layout handler`.

But this layout handler is updated `by function getLayoutUpdateHandle() (Mage_Catalog_Model_Category)`.But  function changing  layout according to condition

we can say that when `a category Anchor is yes (is_anchor value  yes) then magento used layout for that category page:catalog_category_layered`

also when a `category Anchor(is_anchor value  yes) then when a category Anchor is no(is_anchor value  no) then you catalog_category_default`