# Remove js from category layout

Tags: category, layout

I'm trying to remove the jcarousel script (it is located in js/ folder and not skin/ folder) from the category page.
This script is added in local.xml file of my theme:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>hellothemes/jquery.jcarousel.min.js</script></action>
```

Now,
I add this row in the `<default>` tag of catalog.xml:

```
<reference name="head">
 <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>hellothemes/jquery.jcarousel.min.js</name></action>
</reference>
```

but nothing changes.

Any solution?

Comment: see my answer here it my help http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/addjs-css-in-footer-getcssjshtml-not-working/55527#55527

Comment: if this script is used on the home page you can do something wrap it in this <?php 
if( Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home'  && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'cms' ) : ?>
// Put your Script here.
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: I understand your idea but Magento provides the possibility to add/remove css/js in any layout pages and I'd like to follow this solution.

Comment: see may answer it is working for me change <type>js</type> to <type>skin_js</type>

Comment: I've tried it and it has not worked but do attention: if you use skin_js you're saying to Magento to find the file into skin/ folder instead of js/ (as my case)

Comment: try to add under <catalog_category_default translate="label">

Comment: If you have access, then why don't you delete it from `local.xml`, unless you want to remove in specific categories only.

Answer (score 3):

Add JS :

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/owl.carousel.js</name></action>
```

Remove JS :

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/slideshow.js</name></action>
```

Add js files into hellothemes/js

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding this file through your `local.xml` layout, you will want to remove it here also since it is loaded after `catalog.xml`.

Try:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <file>your/file.js</file>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>js</type>
                <file>your/file.js</file>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi pspahn,
you're right.. local.xml is loaded after catalog.xml so I tried adding this code in local.xml file:

<catalog_category_default translate="label">
        <reference name="head">
                <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>hellothemes/jquery.jcarousel.min.js</name></action>
        </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

but it doesn't work again!

In the source code I read:
<script src="http://mysite/js/hellothemes/jquery.jcarousel.min.js" type="text/javascript">
Why?

Comment: I typed this from memory -- `catalog_category_index` should be `catalog_category_view`

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the layout handles specified
although  pspahn's answer is correct  his layout handle is wrong.

I'm quoting marius from the following link to help you further understand the differences in the catalog category layout handles

[Difference between <catalog_category_default> and <catalog_category_view>](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31160/difference-between-catalog-category-default-and-catalog-category-view)

> catalog_category_view is loaded for all the category pages. It's the
>   default layout handler for the category page. The category page maps
>   to the catalog module, category controller, view action.
>
> catalog_category_default is loaded only for categories that are not
>   marked as anchors. There is also a layout handle called
>   catalog_category_layered that is loaded for categories marked as
>   anchor.

Try the following code its a modification of pspahn's answer.

`<layout>
    <default> 
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
                <file>your/file.js</file> </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
    <catalog_category_default> 
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>js</type> 
                <file>your/file.js</file>
            </action> 
        </reference> 
     </catalog_category_default >
    <catalog_category_layered> 
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem">
                <type>js</type> 
                <file>your/file.js</file>
            </action> 
        </reference> 
     </catalog_category_layered >
</layout>`